# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation only return 1 placemark in china

Tags: ios, mkmapview

when i use
[_geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
}

the placemarks only return one

Comment: you mean that you are getting wrong location infomaion?

Comment: no,the placemarks returned only one